# Performance / Concurrency Issue in Pine Script / Trading View

Tags: performance, concurrency, pine-script, tradingview-api

Included is the Code of an indicator which list stocks that are satisfying the conditions of PVT (Price Volume Trend), Volume across three timeframes W, D and 2H.

Because of the Pinescript constraint( Max no. of server calls: 40), I have 13 securities in each indicator instance (13 securities * 3 timeframes = 39 which is still less than 40- Max Sever Calls).

I have created a layout where I have added such indicator instances, 15 of them as I need to check 186 securities.

## Issue Description:

It works perfectly fine listing the stocks that are satisfying conditions. But sometimes (very random) one specific indicator instance will not give output at all though there could be stocks satisfying conditions. If I have to close and reopen the layout, it would list the stocks. In that case, some other indicator instance may not give the output.

I am not sure what is the issue? My guess is it could be to do with performance / concurrency.
When layout gets loaded, 187 securities making 3 calls each to the server, i.e in total 561 calls to the server. Is this an issue? Should I improve any of the implementation out there...

Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Code Implementation of the Indicator:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='WD-p 2H Uptrending_1', shorttitle='WD-p 2H Uptrending_1', format=format.inherit)

//Stochastic-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Returns k value and k's poise flag

get_stochastic_stats(ki,di)=>
    
    k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(ta.rsi(close, 14), ta.rsi(close, 14), ta.rsi(close, 14), 14), ki)
    d = ta.sma(ta.sma(ta.stoch(ta.rsi(close, 14), ta.rsi(close, 14), ta.rsi(close, 14), 14), di), ki)
    [k, k > d ? 1 :-1, k>k[1] ? 1: -1, ta.barssince(ta.crossover(k,d))+1,ta.barssince(ta.crossunder(k,d))+1 ]

get_stochastic_stats_res(_res,ki,di)=>
    [k,k_trend_flag,k_poise_flag,k_crossover_index,k_crossunder_index] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, _res, get_stochastic_stats(ki,di), gaps=barmerge.gaps_off)


//Stochastic-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------


//PVT------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

kEma = 'EMA'
kSma = 'SMA'
kVwma = 'VWMA'
kWma = 'WMA'


// Input
pvt_maType = kEma
pvt_short = 3
pvt_long = 10
pvt_showTrend = false
pvt_showFill = true
pvt_showMa = true
pvt_oscMaType = kSma
pvt_maLength = 13
pvt_cross = true
pvt_shouldNormalize = true
pvt_normalizeLookback = 25

smooth(t, sig, len) =>
    ma = float(sig)  // None
    if t == kSma  // Simple
        ma := ta.sma(sig, len)
        ma
    if t == kEma  // Exponential
        ma := ta.ema(sig, len)
        ma
    if t == kWma  // Weighted
        ma := ta.wma(sig, len)
        ma
    if t == kVwma  // Volume Weighted
        ma := ta.vwma(sig, len)
        ma
    ma

calc_pvt(ma, sig, short, long) =>
    src = sig
    vt = ta.cum(ta.change(src) / src[1] * volume)
    sh = smooth(ma, vt, short)
    lg = smooth(ma, vt, long)
    sh - lg


maxAbs(series, len) =>
    max = float(0)
    for i = 0 to len - 1 by 1
        max := math.max(max, math.abs(series[i]))
        max
    max



get_PVT_VOC_MACD_Stoch_Values_stats() =>
    raw_pvt = calc_pvt(pvt_maType, close, pvt_short, pvt_long)
    maxAbs_pvt = maxAbs(raw_pvt, pvt_normalizeLookback)
    range_pvt = 1.0  // range to fit values into
    value_pvt = pvt_shouldNormalize ? raw_pvt / maxAbs_pvt * range_pvt : raw_pvt

    pvt_poise_flag = value_pvt > value_pvt[1] ? 1 : -1
    pvt_trend_flag = value_pvt > 0 ? 1 : -1
    pvt_cross_over_index = ta.barssince(ta.crossover(value_pvt, 0)) + 1
    pvt_cross_under_index = ta.barssince(ta.crossunder(value_pvt, 0)) + 1
    if pvt_trend_flag == 1
        pvt_cross_under_index := 0
        pvt_cross_under_index
    else
        pvt_cross_over_index := 0
        pvt_cross_over_index

    short = ta.ema(volume, 9)
    long = ta.ema(volume, 21)
    osc = 100 * (short - long) / long

    int voc_co_index = ta.barssince(ta.crossover(osc, 0)) + 1
    if osc <= 0
        voc_co_index := 0
        voc_co_index

    [macdline2, signalLine2, histLine2] = ta.macd(close, 24, 52, 9)

    macdTrend2 = macdline2 > signalLine2 ? 1 : -1

    macd_crossoverIndex2 = ta.barssince(ta.crossover(macdline2, signalLine2)) + 1
    macd_crossunderIndex2 = ta.barssince(ta.crossunder(macdline2, signalLine2)) + 1

    if macdTrend2 == 1
        macd_crossunderIndex2 := 0
        macd_crossunderIndex2
    else
        macd_crossoverIndex2 := 0
        macd_crossoverIndex2
    
    [macdline1, signalLine1, histLine1] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9)

    macdTrend1 = macdline1 > signalLine1 ? 1 : -1

    macd_crossoverIndex1 = ta.barssince(ta.crossover(macdline1, signalLine1)) + 1
    macd_crossunderIndex1 = ta.barssince(ta.crossunder(macdline1, signalLine1)) + 1

    
    if macdTrend1 == 1
        macd_crossunderIndex1 := 0
        macd_crossunderIndex1
    else
        macd_crossoverIndex1 := 0
        macd_crossoverIndex1

    zCrossFlag = -1
    if macdline1 < signalLine1 and macdline1  > macdline1[1] and macdline2 < signalLine2 and macdline2  > macdline2[1]
        zCrossFlag := 3
    else if macdline1 < signalLine1 and macdline1  > macdline1[1]
        zCrossFlag := 1            
    else if macdline2 < signalLine2 and macdline2  > macdline2[1]
        zCrossFlag := 2
    else 
        zCrossFlag := 0
    
    k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(ta.rsi(close, 14), ta.rsi(close, 14), ta.rsi(close, 14), 14), 6)
    d = ta.sma(ta.sma(ta.stoch(ta.rsi(close, 14), ta.rsi(close, 14), ta.rsi(close, 14), 14), 3), 6)

    stoch_trend_flag = 0

    if k >= d
        stoch_trend_flag := 1 
    else
        stoch_trend_flag := -1

    stoch_poise_flag = k>k[1] ? 1: -1

    
    scut = ta.barssince(ta.crossover(k,d))+1
    scdt = ta.barssince(ta.crossunder(k,d))+1

    [value_pvt, pvt_poise_flag, pvt_trend_flag, pvt_cross_over_index, pvt_cross_under_index, osc, osc > -4 ? 1 : -1, voc_co_index, macdTrend1, macd_crossoverIndex1, macd_crossunderIndex1,macdTrend2, macd_crossoverIndex2, macd_crossunderIndex2,zCrossFlag,k, stoch_trend_flag, stoch_poise_flag, scut,scdt]


get_PVT_VOC_MACD_Stoch_Values(sec, _res) =>
    [value_pvt1, pvt_poise_flag1, pvt_trend_flag1, pvt_cross_over_index1, pvt_cross_under_index1, osc, volume_trend_flag, vol_crossover_index, macdTrend1, macd_crossoverIndex1, macd_crossunderIndex1,macdTrend2, macd_crossoverIndex2, macd_crossunderIndex2,zCrossFlag,k,stochTrend,stockPoise,scut,scdt] = request.security(sec, _res, get_PVT_VOC_MACD_Stoch_Values_stats(), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
    [value_pvt1, pvt_poise_flag1, pvt_trend_flag1, pvt_cross_over_index1, pvt_cross_under_index1, osc, volume_trend_flag, vol_crossover_index, macdTrend1, macd_crossoverIndex1, macd_crossunderIndex1,macdTrend2, macd_crossoverIndex2, macd_crossunderIndex2,zCrossFlag,k,stochTrend,stockPoise,scut,scdt]


//PVT------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

textify_number(index) =>
    strNumber = ''
    if index < 10 
        strNumber := '0' + str.tostring(index)
        strNumber
    else
        strNumber := str.tostring(index)
        strNumber
    strNumber

// RoundUp() rounds the given number up to the specified number
// of decimal places.
RoundUp(number, decimals) =>
    factor = math.pow(10, decimals)
    math.ceil(number * factor) / factor 
    
textify_decimal(value) =>
    val = RoundUp(value, 2)
    strNumber    = ""
    if val < 10 and val > 0
        strNumber := '0' + str.tostring(val,"##.##")
    else
        strNumber := str.tostring(val,"##.##")

    if value > 0 
        if str.length(strNumber)== 4
            strNumber := strNumber + '0'
        
        if str.length(strNumber)== 2
            strNumber := strNumber + '.00'
    else if value < 0 
        if str.length(strNumber)== 5
            strNumber := strNumber + '0'
        
        if str.length(strNumber)== 3
            strNumber := strNumber + '.00'
    
    if value > 0
        " " + strNumber
    else
        strNumber

totalPadCharacters = 1

padify(value,padLength) =>
    neededArrows = padLength - str.length(value)
    arrows = "  "
    for offset = 0 to neededArrows - 1
        arrows := arrows + '<'
    arrows:= arrows + "  "  


array_2h_ksopm_uptrend = array.new_string(0)


getData(sec,array_2h_ksopm_uptrend) =>

    [value_pvt_w, pvt_poise_flag_w, pvt_trend_flag_w, pvt_co_w, pvt_cu_w, voc_w, voc_trend_flag_w, voc_co_w, macd1_trend_w, macd1_co_w, macd1_cu_w,macd2_trend_w, macd2_co_w, macd2_cu_w,zCrossFlag_w,k_w,stochTrend_w,stockPoise_w,scut_w,scdt_w] = get_PVT_VOC_MACD_Stoch_Values(sec, 'W')
    [value_pvt_d, pvt_poise_flag_d, pvt_trend_flag_d, pvt_co_d, pvt_cu_d, voc_d, voc_trend_flag_d, voc_co_d, macd1_trend_d, macd1_co_d, macd1_cu_d,macd2_trend_d, macd2_co_d, macd2_cu_d,zCrossFlag_d,k_d,stochTrend_d,stockPoise_d,scut_d,scdt_d] = get_PVT_VOC_MACD_Stoch_Values(sec, 'D')
    [value_pvt_2h, pvt_poise_flag_2h, pvt_trend_flag_2h, pvt_co_2h, pvt_cu_2h, voc_2h, voc_trend_flag_2h, voc_co_2h, macd1_trend_2h, macd1_co_2h, macd1_cu_2h,macd2_trend_2h, macd2_co_2h, macd2_cu_2h,zCrossFlag_2h,k_2h,stochTrend_2h,stockPoise_2h,scut_2h,scdt_2h] = get_PVT_VOC_MACD_Stoch_Values(sec, '120')

    strDelimiter = '_'
    strTimeDelimiter = '  #  '
    strSpaceDelimiter = '    '

    if math.round(k_2h) > 99
        k_2h := 99    
    if math.round(k_d) > 99
        k_d := 99    
    
    if math.round(value_pvt_2h) > 99
        value_pvt_2h := 99    
    if math.round(value_pvt_d) > 99
        value_pvt_d := 99    
        
    if value_pvt_w > 0 and value_pvt_d > 0 and value_pvt_2h > 0 and stochTrend_2h == 1 and voc_2h > 0 
        data = textify_number(math.round(k_2h)) + strSpaceDelimiter +  textify_number(scut_2h) + strDelimiter + textify_number(voc_co_2h)  + strDelimiter + textify_number(pvt_co_2h) + strDelimiter +  textify_number(macd1_co_2h) + strDelimiter + textify_number(macd2_co_2h) + strSpaceDelimiter + textify_decimal(voc_2h) 
        data := data + strSpaceDelimiter
        data := data + textify_number(scut_w) + strDelimiter + textify_number(voc_co_w)  + strDelimiter + textify_number(pvt_co_w)
        data := data + strTimeDelimiter + str.replace_all(sec, 'NSE:', '') 

        if zCrossFlag_2h > 0
            data := data + " < 2H " + str.tostring(zCrossFlag_2h)
        if zCrossFlag_d > 0
            data := data + " < D " + str.tostring(zCrossFlag_d)
        if zCrossFlag_w > 0
            data := data + " < W " + str.tostring(zCrossFlag_w)

        array.push(array_2h_ksopm_uptrend, data)
    


sec_1="NSE:APOLLOTYRE"
sec_2="NSE:ASHOKLEY"
sec_3="NSE:BAJAJ_AUTO"
sec_4="NSE:BALKRISIND"
sec_5="NSE:BOSCHLTD"
sec_6="NSE:EICHERMOT"
sec_7="NSE:ESCORTS"
sec_8="NSE:EXIDEIND"
sec_9="NSE:HEROMOTOCO"
sec_10="NSE:M_M"
sec_11="NSE:MARUTI"
sec_12="NSE:MOTHERSON"
sec_13="NSE:MRF"



getData(sec_1, array_2h_ksopm_uptrend)
getData(sec_2, array_2h_ksopm_uptrend)
getData(sec_3, array_2h_ksopm_uptrend)
getData(sec_4, array_2h_ksopm_uptrend)
getData(sec_5, array_2h_ksopm_uptrend)
getData(sec_6, array_2h_ksopm_uptrend)
getData(sec_7, array_2h_ksopm_uptrend)
getData(sec_8, array_2h_ksopm_uptrend)
getData(sec_9, array_2h_ksopm_uptrend)
getData(sec_10, array_2h_ksopm_uptrend)
getData(sec_11, array_2h_ksopm_uptrend)
getData(sec_12, array_2h_ksopm_uptrend)
getData(sec_13, array_2h_ksopm_uptrend)

array.sort(array_2h_ksopm_uptrend, order.ascending)


string str_2h_ksopm_uptrend = ''


for i = 0 to array.size(array_2h_ksopm_uptrend) == 0 ? na : array.size(array_2h_ksopm_uptrend) - 1 by 1
    str_2h_ksopm_uptrend += str.tostring(array.get(array_2h_ksopm_uptrend, i)) + ' \n'


cellWidth = 100

var table atrDisplay = table.new(position.top_right, 1, 2,border_width =1 )
table.cell(atrDisplay,0, 0, "K      S   O    P   M1  M2     V         S   O   P   #  2H  W Uptrending", text_color=color.white, text_halign=text.align_left, width=cellWidth)
table.cell(atrDisplay,0, 1, str.tostring(str_2h_ksopm_uptrend), text_color=color.rgb(174, 243, 167), text_halign=text.align_left, width=cellWidth)
'''
```